# Verify that $\frac{1}{\tan(x) \csc(x)} = \cos(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Please Help! I have been struggling with this problem for far too long. I have tried rewriting $\tan(x)$ as $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ in the denominator then simplifying the denominator, but I get stuck there.

Comment: What do you get when you simplify the denominator? What is $$\frac{\sin x }{\cos x} \frac{1}{\sin x}$$

Comment: That's exactly where I get stuck.

Comment: @Dora what is $\frac{u}{u}$? Now let $u=\sin(x)$.

Comment: Do you see that the sine terms cancel?

Comment: my hints: do u know $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$ & $\cosec x=1/\sin x$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\tan x\csc x}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\frac1{\sin x}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos x}}=\cos x$$

Comment: How did you get from (sinx/cosx)(1/sinx) to 1/cosx?

Comment: @Dora When you multiply by something and then divide by the same thing, it is as if you didn't do it at all; therefore we say that the two things cancel. GoodDeeds saw that $\sin(x)$ was both multiplied and divided in the expression, so they cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\tan(x)\csc(x)}=\frac{1}{\tan(x)\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\tan(x)}{\sin(x)}}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\tan(x)}=\cos(x)$$